# QGIS - Split Vector Layer returns empty layer

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, splitting

I'm to split a vector layer by feature with "split vector layer" tool in qgis
I want to split the "switchboar" column

[image: original table]

after I fill the tool

[image: tool]

I receive the new empty layer

[image: empty]

Does anybody know why I don't get different layers separated by the attribute?
I must say that if there is a NULL value I get only one layer with the NULL values and that's it.

---

I must say that I solved the issue by using SAGA software (split table tool)
but still it's less comfortable then using QGIS alone.

Comment: Which qgis version is this?

Comment: Can't reproduce with QGIS 2.18, but this version is already using processing toolbox for vector analysis. Try also to use analysis from processing toolbox, if the result will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I used SAGA software (split table tool)
it's less comfartable then QGIS alone but still works fine

Comment: just a tip: you can use SAGA tools also directly from QGIS. See [processing toolbox documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html).